# What is the condition that the following sum of recursive integrals is bounded?

Tags: integration, summation, recursion

I’ve come across the following recursive formula
$$f_{i}(t)=\int_{t’}G(t,t’)f_{i-1}(t’)dt’$$
for $i>1$ where $f_{1}(t)$ and the kernel $G(t,t’)$ are known. I was wondering under what conditions on the kernel the sum
$$S(t)=\sum_{i>1}f_{i}(t)$$
is bounded? I would appreciate any reference material considering properties of such integral summations.

Comment: One sufficient condition would be $\forall $t$, \int_{t'}G\,dt' < m$ for some $m < 1$. Then $\sup |f_i| \le m \sup |f_{i-1}|$ and $S$ is majorized by $\sup f_1 \sum_i m^i < \infty$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the comment. Is there any general theorem on such summations including integral form and kernels? Because I'm also wondering what if $G$ is singular.